# Jasmine spies not being called

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am having some trouble implimenting spying in Jasmine

I want to check if a link has been clicked on a slider using a jasmine spy and jasmine jquery.

Here is a simplified version:

I have some links as part of an html fixture file.

```
<a href="#" class="someLink">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="someLink">Link 2</a>
```

slider:

```
var Slider = function(links){
    this.sliderLinks = $(links);
    this.bindEvents();
}

Slider.prototype.bindEvents = function(){
    this.sliderLinks.on('click', this.handleClick);
}

Slider.prototype.handleClick = function(e){
    console.log('i have been clicked')
}
```

spec file:

```
describe('Slider', function(){
    var slider;

    beforeEach(function(){
        loadFixtures('slider.html');

        slider = new Slider('.someLink');

    });

    it('should handle link click', function(){
        spyOn(slider, 'handleClick');
        $(slider.sliderLinks[0]).trigger('click');
        expect(slider.handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

The test is failing. But the 'i have been clicked' has been logged to the console so the method is being called.

If I do this the test passes though:

```
it('should handle link click', function(){
        spyon(slider, 'handleClick');
        slider.handleClick();
        expect(slider.handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

So my question essentially is:

1. Am i testing for this type of thing in the wrong way?
2. why is the spy not registering the fact that the method has been called?

Comment: I guess in this case you should *spy on the prototype*: `spyOn(Slider.prototype, 'handleClick')` and put this code before the `Slider` creation `new Slider(...)` (as @EliranMalka commented). Have you tried this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've just verified the solution outlined in the comment. Your `describe` should be:

```
describe('Slider', function () {

    var slider;

    beforeEach(function () {
        loadFixtures('slider.html');
        spyOn(Slider.prototype, 'handleClick');
        slider = new Slider('.someLink');
    });

    it('should handle link click', function (){
        $(slider.sliderLinks[0]).trigger('click');
        expect(slider.handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

The point is that you have to spy on prototype `handleClick` function and *before* the `Slider` creation.

The reason is what Jasmine `spyOn` really does in the code you provided:

```
spyOn(slider, 'handleClick');
```

creates slider property `handleClick` (containing the spy object) directly on the `slider` instance. `slider.hasOwnProperty('handleClick')` in this case returns `true`, you know...

But still, there is `handleClick` prototype property to which your click event is bound. That means just triggered click event is handled by the prototype `handleClick` function while the slider object own property `handleClick` (your spy) stays untouched.

So the answer is that the spy is not registering the fact that the method has been called because it has never been called :-)

Comment: +1 your explanation of prototype vs own property is spot on and is not mentioned anywhere in the docs. thanks very much!